# How to configure graphite web with cyanite

Tags: cassandra, graphite, whisper

I am new to graphite, and i want to replace the whisper db with Cassandra with the help of cyanite. I downloaded cyanite from
https://github.com/pyr/cyanite . But i am unable to figure out what to do after downloading this. I couldn't find any steps or documentation to follow, nor could i find relevant links in the net.

Also is can someone explain me the pros and cons of using cyanite vs carbon_cassandra _plugin along with megacarbon?

Are there any alternatives for cyanite, which are better than cyanite?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We stick to cassandra as storage backend because of it's datacenter-aware (data spread in many location/zones) and relatively easy scaling (up/out).

So we start with testing using cyanite. But eventually we dropped it because of [read performance regression](https://github.com/pyr/cyanite/issues/156). As I see it moved forward, but frankly I wasn't following it - will review it in the future.

Next we give a shot to [disthene](https://github.com/EinsamHauer/disthene). Pros compare to cyanite:

- "native" webapp implementation (not all functions)
- at a time it looks stable(vide cyanite issues)
- multitenant (need some works)
- and last java  (arguable https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/clojure.html)

Currently we are using disthene, tested with 2.5M/min without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just to comment on

> (arguable https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/clojure.html)

The problem with Clojure is not the performance but rather arguable concurrency/channels/etc design. In particular one of the problems with cyanite (at least earlier versions) was that it dead locked under heavy load somewhere inside channels. And that is somehow expected AFAIU. (like mentioned here: http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html)